# can't see backgound image when i run my app on android phone

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

i"m developing an app with android studio. when i"m running my app on one phone and i"m able to see the background image but when i run the app on another phone i"m not able to see the background and i only see a white background instead. i did try to change the background to another image and i i"m able to see it ,what can be the problem?

this is the activity.xml file:

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.myapp.myapplication.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:background="@drawable/thewallpaper"
    >
```

the image details :

dimensions: 1080X1920
size: 1MB
type: PNG file

the logcast is:

```
04-02 15:37:13.998 24933-24933/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni 
04-02 15:37:13.998 24933-24933/? I/art: VMHOOK: rlim_cur : 0 pid:24933 
04-02 15:37:14.208 24933-24933/com.example.yuliaaa.myapplication E/Typeface: SANS_LOC file not found. 
04-02 15:37:15.069 24933-24933/com.example.yuliaaa.myapplication D/Atlas: Validating map... 
04-02 15:37:15.159 24933-25005/com.example.yuliaaa.myapplication I/Adreno-EGL: : EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.AF.1.1_RB1.05.00.02.006.020 - CR771817 () OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.06 Build Date: 03/04/15 Wed Local Branch: Remote Branch: refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.AF.1.1_RB1.05.00.02.006.020 Local Patches: NONE Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING 
04-02 15:37:15.370 24933-25005/com.example.yuliaaa.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (3240x5760, max=4096x4096)
```

Comment: send your logcat please

Comment: Try using an image loading library like Picasso or Glide

Comment: Try to set your image in ImageView inside Relative layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your image in **Qualified Res Folders**: `drawable-XXXdpi` like this : `drawable-hdpi` to prevent scaling image in high density screen devices by android.

for more information check this:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html